# Will Asynch Ecommerce Code work with Universal GA?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, universal-analytics, data-layers

Total revenue comes through properly for an order, but when you click into the Transaction ID, the breakdown of products and product revenue is incorrect.

We are on Universal GA, however just realized that the ecommerce code is still using the Asynchronous syntax. Not using GTM, rather the code is placed on the final order confirmation page. Also Enhanced ecommerce is not turned on.

Would this be causing the data discrepancy in GA, or do I need to keep digging?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to keep digging. Transactions are pretty much self-contained,  the different syntax will not cause discrepancies between transactions and products. Note that the transaction total is not the sum of the product totals, it's passed in separately, so differences might be due to wrongly passed totals.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that being on a custom CMS requires some customization of the ecomm tracking code? Obviously it's not working as is; individual items are not passing through correctly.